# CNAME DNS delegation

Tags: dns, cname

Just want to confirm/correct my understanding of how CNAME delegation works

if I have a CNAME cdn.example.com in my DNS that points to a third party CNAME cdn.thirdparty.com,
can that third party register  an A record in their DNS along the lines of
test.cdn.thirdparty.com   ?

i.e can they register 2nd level subdomains if their name server is now effectively responsible for resolving cdn.thirdparty.com ?
or can only register an A record for cdn.thirdparry.com ?

Thanks

Comment: CNAME is used to define a sub/sub-domain/domain that goes to another sub/sub-domain/domain. So third party can only use CNAME to point to another sub/sub-domain/domain i.e. cdn.thirdparty.com to cdn.fourthparty.com. They can define an A record if they want to have test.cdn.thirdparty.com. Relevant question was already answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225526/can-i-use-cname-records-for-subdomain-and-sub-subdomain